# Shell scripts with options

Tags: linux, shell

i want to write a script,which, while executing, should look like -

```
./script.sh -o1 option1 -o2 -o3 option3 ...
```

and the output should be like this-

```
option1
option3
```

How can i achieve it?

Comment: As a rule, you should explain what you've tried. If nothing else, it shows what efforts you've made to solve the problem yourself first. See [this blog post](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need switches ("-o1" etc.), there is a simple solution. Command line options appear in variables named "$1", "$2" etc. Such as

```
me@computer:~> ./script.sh option1 option2 option3
option1
option2
option3
```

script.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the bash [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) builtin. e.g. (from that linked tutorial)

```
while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: when i execute this script

`./script.sh -a hello`

it should display hello with the same number of switch statements. That's what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [Parsing Command Line Options in Shell Scripts](http://blog.mafr.de/2007/08/05/cmdline-options-in-shell-scripts/)